# Android - Quick launch actions when holding on app icon

Tags: android

This is an example implemented in Google Maps to quickly set up a destination.

I need to do the same thing, but for custom actions. Is this possible? If so how?

[image: example]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1.html#shortcuts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android we call it as App Shortcuts it will be supported from Android N and above. You can refer to [github link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AppShortcuts) by Google for sample